# how to send the commands to a full duplex port

Tags: port

I am using XCOM v2.0. It comes with a hardware, and it will receive the data from the port com4 continuously, also sometimes I need to send command to this port com4 to control that hardware. The trick thing is, there is a option called "send new lines" in XCOM V2.0, If I want to send a command to the port, I have to check it to let the command work, otherwise the command will not work.

My goal is to understand this, and implement this command in my python code. Currently I could use XCOM V2.0 to real-time receive the data and send commands. But my python code does not work.

So XCOM V2.0 did something for my command, but how could I know? I do not have the firmware of that hardware, how could I monitor the com4 and see what commands I send to port com4? so I could do same thing in my python code?

at first I thought XCOM V2.0 just add \r or \n or any combination after/before my commands, but I tried every possbile combination and none of them work, you could even try this in XCOM V2.0, just add \n or \r or combination in the end of command, and do not check "send new lines", it will not work. Later I though XCOM V2.0 must send some hidden commands to stop the port receiving, and do sending, but how to figure out it?

Comment: It seems you need any sdk of the hardware for py, or you need any technical reference of the hardware protocol before you create an establish communication from py into the hardware.

Comment: I could receive the data from this port with python, but when I try to send the command, no response. I could use python to send some commands to other port (connected with different hardware) and it works fine.

Comment: Are you sure the hardware has no any protocol for negotiation or any aknowledge command to build communication? Btw you can make sure by read the technical reference for that hardware specificallly associated to that matter.

Comment: thanks, that is a mcu and I will try to find its firmware, but in general, if a port is receiving data, shouldn't we send some stop commands to let the port stop the receiving the data, then send my command to the hardware? I guess this is the reason why my python code not working.

Comment: You re welcome. What you say refer to particular standard protocol, and there is stop bit also. But practically the system control the port for any incoming or outgoing signal over serial bus.